# Read latency of Datastore

Tags: java, sdk, vmware, latency, datastore

what is read latency of a datastore in vmware. How to calculate it. Is there any relation between read latency of various ESXI hosts to which that datastore is connected?

Answer (score 0):

Read latency is the amount of time taken by a VM to read the data on the datastore. 
Normally this depends between the esxi host and the SAN from which the datastore is presented. 
Having high read latency will slow down your VMs.

It is easy to see the latency on vmware, you just have to click on a VM or a host and then go the performance tab where you can have graphs to show it.